Modify the run-name into uppercase of workflow github actions
How can we modify the case of the word in the "run-name"?
This is my workflow:
name: Test workflow
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        required: true
        type: choice
        description: Select the environment
        options:
          - 'dev'
          - 'test'
          - 'prod'
        default : 'dev'

run-name: >-
  Trial - ${{ inputs.environment }}       

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: [self-hosted-runner]
    steps:
      - name: Dummy workflow
        run: echo "dummy workflow"

I want run name to be like this if we choose environment to be dev then Trial - DEV or if we choose environment to be test then Trial - TEST or if we choose environment to be prod then Trial - PROD. How can we achieve this. Basically we need to change the case of word

Is there a reason why you're not using uppercase directly on the input options list and default value?

Obviously Yes, there is a reason. Because I am using self hosted runner where dev,test and prod are being used in lower case. @GuiFalourd

I've made some tests here in this workflow file and you can achieve what you want by using an expression.
A solution is to use the following expression:
run-name: Trial - ${{ inputs.environment == 'dev' && 'DEV' || inputs.environment == 'test' && 'TEST' || 'PROD' }}


You would need to add more inputs.environment == 'env' && 'ENV' || configs if new environments need to be supported as well in the future.
Note that the workflow run-name field only accepts expressions using the github, inputs and vars context.

Thanks for your response. Yep it is right. Even I did the same. Can we optimise this?

I don't think it's possible to optimize this behavior at the moment (I'm not aware of other working alternative).
